# Local JSON file does not work with easyautocomplete

Tags: json, local, easyautocomplete

How to connect a local JSON file correctly? And does EasyAutocomplete work with a local JSON file?
For example, this code does not work:

```
var options = {
  url: "../Desktop/res/countries.json",
  getValue: "name",
};

$("#provider").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

All the other examples I used didn't work either.

Comment: you can't access local files from a browser, for security reasons. It will try to fetch it from the webserver which the page was served from. If you served the page over file:/// it almost certainly won't work at all. Use a webserver to test over http:// instead.